# Hibernate Parameter annotation value from application.yaml

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Is it possible to use some variable from application.yaml in hibernate model class as a parameter instead of hard coded value.

ex.

```
@GenericGenerator(
    name = "generator",
    strategy = "cool.nice.package.NiceClass",
    parameters = {
    @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(
    name = "service", value = "niceValue"),
    }
)
```

I tired this way but it didn't work.

```
@GenericGenerator(
    name = "generator",
    strategy = "cool.nice.package.NiceClass",
    parameters = {
    @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(
    name = "service", value = "${value}"),
    }
)
```

In application.yaml

```
value: "niceValue"
```

Is there any other way to make this value generic?

I'm using Spring 4.3.5, spring boot 1.4.3. and hibernate 5.0.11.Final.

Answer (score 0):

I would do that in the following way:

```
@PropertySource(ignoreResourceNotFound = true, value = "classpath:application.yaml")
@Entity
public class HbnModel{

    @Value("${value}")
    private String valueHere;

    @GenericGenerator(
        name = "generator",
        strategy = "cool.nice.package.NiceClass",
        parameters = {
        @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(
        name = "service", value = valueHere),
        }
    )
    privte String someValue;

    // Getters and Setter

}
```

Comment: unfortunately not. i'm getiing a message that this variable should be constant. :/